# Moment JS, How can I generate an array of days from a selected month?

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I need to build an array containing two date values: day_number, day_name.
I am using a select button to choose the month and I plan on displaying said days horizontally across a grid.
Something like this:

```
              fri sat sun mon tue wed thu fri sat sun mon ...
2019-January   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11 ...
```

I'm trying to get this done with MomentJS but I can't seem to figure out how to do this, so any help or suggestions are welcome, thanks in advance. :D

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the number of days in a month. Try editing the function to get the first day of the week and then circularly iterate through a list of the days of the week until you’ve reached the end of the value of the last day.

```
function getNoOfDays(date) { 
   
   return moment(date, "YYYY-MM").daysInMonth()  
} 

   
// Function call 

var result = getNoOfDays("2019-03"); 

console.log("No of days in given date is:", result);
```